# Weird behavior of spotlight & program icons

Tags: macos, spotlight

My spotlight is acting a bit scatchy, it shows every program as a rar? archive.

Did a rebuild of the index file.
Did a repair permissions.

Who can Help me?

[image: Strange spotlight]

Comment: I have this same issue. It goes away after a reboot, but comes back afterwards. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sadly still no!

Answer (score 1):

Thread about this problem at [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5609797?tstart=0)

This is open bug known by Apple, as mentioned by [rei_vilo](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5609797?start=15&tstart=0) Mar 28, 2014

Temporary solutions might be:

- Permission Repair with Disk Utility
- Rebuild Launch Services Database `sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed`
- Restart the SystemUIServer `killall -HUP SystemUIServer`
- Rebuild Spotlight index `sudo mdutil -E /`
- If installed Parallel Desktop turn off "Share Windows applications with Mac"

Answer (score 0):

#### Restart the SystemUIServer

```
killall -HUP SystemUIServer
```

#### Reboot into Safe Mode

Boot holding ⇧, login, wait a bit, then reboot normally.

Comment: Oke sadly they reappear after some time... at first they look fine! after a couple of minutes, they start to change to that rar file icon again... sadly :(